# jquery get json with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, audio

I am working with a music player that need to get json value from a page dynamically the first thing i am struggling is the json is some thing like this

```
{"audios":[{"audio":{"name":"makakyala","audio":{"audio":{"url":"/uploads/audio    /audio/9/01_-_Makkayala_SouthSongs4u.com_.mp3"}}}},{"audio":{"name":"tahppellam","audio":{"audio":{"url":"/uploads/audio/audio/10/03_-_Thapellam_Thape_Illai_SouthSongs4u.com_.mp3"}}}},{"audio":{"name":"dinam dinam","audio":{"audio":{"url":"/uploads/audio/audio/11/04_-_Dinnam_Dinnam_SouthSongs4u.com_.mp3"}}}}]}
```

I need each audio array to be passed to  jquery and my jquery code is

```
$.getJSON("../albums/x.json",function(json){  
    $.each(json.audios,function(index, audio){
       $.each(audio, function(audio) {
        as=JSON.stringify(audio)
        alert(as)
        myPlaylist.add({title:$(this).attr("audio_name")}); 
     })
        })
     });
```

but its not working what is the problem with my code and how can i get each audio array form audios array ?

Comment: `$.each(audio, function(idx, audio) {` change to this in your second each loop.

Comment: thank you, changed like this but nothing works                    $.getJSON("../albums/x.json",function(json){  
    $.each(json.audios,function(index, audio){
       $.each(audio, function(index, audio) {
        as=JSON.stringify(audio)
        alert(audio)
        myPlaylist.add({title:$(this).attr("audio_name")}); 
     })
        })
     });

Comment: Can't get it, what is your expected output?/ what it should do?

Comment: yeah now working well with your code thanks bro very much

Comment: the output is some thing like   {"name":"makakyala","audio":{"audio":{"url":"/uploads/audio/audio/9/01_-_Makkayala_SouthSongs4u.com_.mp3"}}} now to get audio_url i have to put another each loop or something else?

Comment: you don't need to have another `$.each()` loop you can get it in your second loop with this `audio.audio.audio.url` http://jsfiddle.net/Dk7rh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this :

```
$.each(audio, function(audio) {
```

to this:

```
$.each(audio, function(idx, audio) {
```

---

In your second `$.each()` iteration you need to put it as a second argument because first arg or if single arg passed in the callback gives you the key of the js object not the object itself. So you need to put this in second argument as suggested above.

---

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dk7rh/)

---

This will get you the url you are looking for:

```
$.each(audio, function(idx, audio) {
    console.log(audio.audio.audio.url);
});
```

### [Demo to get the each url](http://jsfiddle.net/Dk7rh/1/)

Comment: thanks bro works well the output is like this {"name":"makakyala","audio":{"audio":{"url":"/uploads/audio/audio/9/01_-_Makkayala_SouthSongs4u.com_.mp3"}}} i have to extract each element from this array bu the url is inside the audios what should i do again another each loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code. Check what header you passing when sending the response.
You should set response header as `header('Content-Type: application/json');`